# PL SQL - select column_name from user_triggers always returns an empty string

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g

I'm doing a script in pl/sql where I create triggers creation scripts using data from "user_triggers" view. I need to get the name of the column referenced by the trigger. It's value should be in "column_name" from "user_triggers" view. But when I'm selecting the column_name value always returns and empty string, even if I have a script like that:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_update_price
 BEFORE UPDATE OF PRET ON produse
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

USER_TRIGGERS.COLUMN_NAME is only filled in for nested table triggers, which you're not creating.  You might want to look at the TRIGGERING_EVENT column to get the information you're looking for.  Share and enjoy.